# Really big retrieval lag for Logstash Kafka inputs producing data irregularly

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm using logstash 2.4 with kafka input 5.1.6. In my config I created a field called input_lag in order to monitor how much time it takes logstash to process logs:

```
ruby {
      code => "event['lag_seconds'] = (Time.now.to_f - event['@timestamp'].to_f)"
}
```

I listen to several kafka topics from a single logstash instance and for the topics that produce logs regularly everything is OK and the lag is small (several seconds). However, for the topics that produce small amount of logs irregularly I get really big lags. Sometimes it's tens of thousands of seconds.
My configuration for Kafka input is following:

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "kafka-broker1:6667,kafka-broker2:6667,kafka-broker3:6667"
        add_field => { "environment" => "my_env" }
        topics_pattern => "a|lot|of|topics|like|60|of|them"
        decorate_events => true
        group_id => "mygroup1"
        codec => json
        consumer_threads => 10
        auto_offset_reset => "latest"
        auto_commit_interval_ms => "5000"
   }
}
```

The logstash instance seems healthy, as logs from other topics are being retrieved regularly. I've checked and if I connect to Kafka using its console consumer the delayed logs are there. I've also thought that it might be a problem with too many topics being served by a single logstash instance and extracted those small topics to separate logstash instances but the lag is exactly the same, so it's not the issue.

Any ideas? I suspect that logstash might be using some exponential delay for log retrieval, but have no idea how to confirm and fix that.

Comment: If I were you I would first test with one topic, then two, then three, etc, until you start witnessing the issue. Then I would also try with a single topic that produces a small amount of irregular logs, then two, etc. It would be nice to get such insights.

Comment: have you made any progress so far?

Comment: @Val Sorry for delay. I've been dealing with some other staff. I will respond more thoroughly tomorrow. But to let you know now. I've tested all the cases and it doesn't matter how many apps I run, the lag is always the same (perfectly the same). I've run 2 instances of logstash, one with multiple topics (>50) and one with a single rarely producing topic. The lag was perfectly identical between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Still lack some information:

- Kafaka client version?
- What's the content of `@timestamp`?
- What's the order of filter? Is ruby last one?
- > the delayed logs are there -- 'there' means in Kafaka?

#### Timestamp

If we didn't use `date` filter to change this field, `@timestamp` should be the time at which the log entry was read.

In this case, the lag ups to seconds, so I guess the `date` filter is used and timestamp here is the time when log generated.

#### Wait Before Fetch

When use Kafka input plugin to consume message, it will wait some time before server respond. This can be configured by two options:

- fetch_max_wait_ms
- poll_timeout_ms

You many check them in config file.

#### Wait Before Filter

Logstash handles input log in batch to improve performance, so if not enough logs comes, it will wait some time.

- pipeline.batch.delay

You may check it in `logstash.yml`.

#### Metric

Logstash itself has the metric information generate, combined with Elasticseach and Kibana, can be very handy to use. So I suggest you to have a try.

#### Ref

- [Kafka Input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-poll_timeout_ms)
- [Logstash Config](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html)
- [ELK Monitoring](https://rmoff.net/2016/05/13/monitoring-logstash-ingest-rates-with-elasticsearch-kibana-and-timelion/)